# ngShow/ngHide fadeout animation not working

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to fadeout a message text after some n seconds. I have tried something like this
http://plnkr.co/edit/U3tqlSrRwieKH33GePfe

but its not working, after 8 seconds the text message is hiding immediately.

Answer (score 0):

In your plunker above you delete the message before being able to animate the text. In fact, your div container animates (its opacity is transitioned to 0) but you cannot see it because of the missing text.

Another point is to use either ng-show or ng-class when trying to animate elements. Using both of them force you to overwrite the classes added to the element and can make your code quite confusing.

You can test the plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/xeaCKIaCRIrDiYVxsggh?p=preview)

Comment: So I think I should used js based animation here i.e. on setTimeout using jquery fadeOut..